# Prehistoric times (maybe), girl can see auras

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book a few years ago and it’s stuck with me but I can’t for the life of me remember the title. I only remember odd scenes. I know it’s told by a young girl from maybe before Viking times? She can see auras and she was left in her hut with her younger brother when a man knocked, threatened and later kidnapped her.

I can also remember she was saved by another man who took her on a boat and they kinda fell in love but when they stopped somewhere she picked some healing herbs that belonged to a clan or something so she was kidnapped again. The guy married the chiefs daughter in exchange for her freedom. The two woman obviously hate each other and later on in the story the other woman kills the original woman’s horse as a gift for the gods.

There’s a few more details but this question is long enough.

Comment: No, please tell us all the details you can!

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anymore details? For example, how long ago was a few years ago? Also nothing is too small to tell us so add everything you can remember!

Comment: Are "home healing herbs" a noun by themselves? Did the chief's daughter kill "a gift for the gods" or did she kill the horse *as* a gift for the gods?